# Copy nodes in AST

Tags: java, parsing, copy, abstract-syntax-tree, javaparser

I am using [javaparser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) to construct an AST from Java source code.
Is there a way to safely copy AST nodes?

For example, if I want to duplicate a BinaryExpr to insert somewhere else in the tree, is there a built-in way to copy the node?

Comment: How about visitor pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the CloneVisitor (https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/blob/master/javaparser-core/src/main/java/com/github/javaparser/ast/visitor/CloneVisitor.java)

Maybe we should make it more obvious, I will open an issue at (https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/issues/147)

Disclaimer: I am a JavaParser contributor